# How much damage does a coffin do?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, equipment, improvised-weaponry

I've been looking through various supplies to buy for my campaign as a Bloodrager/Fighter and I found that coffins are a thing. So I'm wondering how much damage would it do? would it be like a greataxe/greatsword or a club?

Comment: The Meat Man Commeth! Welcome to rpg.se, take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Are you looking to use a coffin as your primary weapon or simply want to know how much damage it does should you decide to use it as one? Either way we should be able to answer, good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 3):

### It's an improvised weapon

The **pathfinder 1e Core handbook** has all the details in the **weapons section**, you mainly get a **-4 penalty** when using it.

*Catch offguard* and *improvised weapon mastery* feats can help you minimize the penalities for using it and even help you get a little edge with them.

Deciding how much damage does takes a bit of a subjective approach, as the manual says you should apply the damage of a similar weapon of the same size.

Taking in account that a coffin is a **blunt weapon** that's **bigger than the person that's suposed to be inside it**, I'd, personally compare it to a *large  greatclub*, this would make it do **2d8 blunt damage**, and would add an **additional penalty of -2** for the size difference with the wielder thus giving you a **-6 total penalty** should a medium creature use a medium sized coffin as a weapon.

As using a two handed weapon that's a size larger than the character is not possible, you'd need to either get 2 levels in the Titan Mauler barbarian archetype, or look for a way to consider the character a large creature (like using the enlarge person spell).

Comment: (I'm not clear on if this answer is taking into account that a typical Medium creature just can't wield a Large greatclub.)

Comment: I do agree that the question could be improved by pointing that out (and maybe even pointing to a/some of the way(s) it is actually possible), but I don't think it's necessary per the scope of the question.

Comment: You might also note that a wooden coffin will quite probably break if used as a weapon. It isn't designed for that at all, and is a fair bit weaker than a solid piece of wood the same size.

Comment: @John Dallman not only that, if you would try to wield a coffin as a wepaon you'd basically be a siting duck, since you need to hold it like a ram and it's not balanced at all. But I think those details are up for GM interpretation.